# 2 TextBlocks in ScrollView.

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing a page, that needs 1 article in bold and second normal.

Texts can be very long, so I need a scroll view of the page. Example of the page:

[image: Page Sample]

And here is the code of my Grid.Row that is Content:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="ArticleContent" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

When I run this code - nothing apears on the screen

Comment: +1 for freehand circles :)

Comment: This article might be helpful: [Creating Scrollable TextBlock for WP7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)

Comment: nothing appears because there is no text in textblock :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is being displayed you have not set the text of the `textblocks`.

You can set text manually by `Text = "fdjhldjfgldkgd"`

or you can use binding `Text ="{Binding asd}"`.

One more thing you should also set the foreground of the `textblock` as black or any desired color.

If your text length is too much and you want to wrap the the text then you will have to use `TextWrapping = Wrap`

hope this might help..

Answer (score 1):

Set your TextBlock's Text property to the content that you want in there

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
```

If it needs to be bound to a data backend this could be done either in code behind or through wpf

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding x}"/>
or
Binding B = new Binding("x");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(ArticleContent, TextBlock.TextProperty, B);
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for help, i had the stupidest problem: Text color was white (facepalm)